# Adding CSS Sheet to Intellij JavaFX project

Tags: java, css, intellij-idea, javafx, intellij-14

I am trying to add CSS to a JavaFX project that I am developing in IntelliJ. I have a CSS style-sheet named "list-view.css" and want to attach it to my project. Here's a screenshot of my project's directory:

[Project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z6UR.png)

The file is located in the same directory as the Main file that I have attached the code for. When I print out the value of the variable url, I keep on getting "null" and keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.kernaldrive.startupscreen.Main.start(Main.java:72)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.kernaldrive.startupscreen.Main
```

I checked out this answer: [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other)

But this was not able to solve it unfortunately. Here is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);     //removes minimize and fullscreen button

    Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
    double screenWidth = screenBounds.getWidth();
    double screenHeight = screenBounds.getHeight();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Homepage - KernalDrive");

    Pane layout = new Pane();

    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 1920, 1080);
    URL url = getClass().getResource("listView.css");
    String css = url.toExternalForm();
    scene.getStylesheets().add(css);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

EDIT: I have fixed the  URL url = getClass().getResource("listView.css"); but am still getting the same issue!

Comment: In the answer to [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other) did you read the "_Maven (and similar) standard layouts_" section? Because based on your project directory layout you're using Maven, Gradle, or something similar yet you erroneously have the CSS file in the `src/main/java` directory.

Comment: In other words, try having the file as `src/main/resources/com/kernaldrive/startupscreen/list-view.css` and then `Main.class.getResource("list-view.css")` should work for you.

Comment: now what _is_ the name of your css? clean out the project and do a clean build from scratch. If it persists, follow the troubleshooting section of the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to type in the same name as the file:

you typed listView.css but your file is called list-view.css

now your code looks like this:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("list-view.css");
```

Comment: I tried this but it still hasn't fixed the issue unfortunately

Comment: okay, this works for me, i recreated the problem on my pc and this fixes it but i am not working with maven or else in my javafx project